# TransactionID Creation

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions

I have following method to create transactioID, I wonder if it create same id while multthread execution
What kind of problem I can come across with the method?

```
private String getTransactionId(){
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
        buf.append(this.getPrefix());
        buf.append(this.getApplicationId());
        buf.append(this.getThreadId());
        buf.append(System.currentTimeMillis());

        try{
            Thread.sleep(1);
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        while(buf.length()<19){
            buf.append("0");
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can assume that the this.getPrefix(), getApplicationID() and getThreadID() methods are themselves thread safe, than this method is thread safe.  It is not accessing any of the object's members.

The StringBuffer object is only accessible via the `buf` variable on calling thread's stack, and so it is only accessible via the thread that created it.

Comment: you are right, at least this.getThreadId() paremters makes transactionID unique even if all others are same.